# VB.NET - Function Cannot Modify a Member Of An Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byref

I'm trying to pass an Array to a Sub so the Sub can modify one of the values of the array.

Something like this

```
Dim a As String = "STARTVALUE"

PopulateDataSet("Management", {a})

Public Sub PopulateDataSet(ByRef SomeRandomOtherVariable As String, ByRef ToBePopulatedVariables() As String)

    ToBePopulatedVariables(0) = "TheNewValue"

End Sub
```

When I run the code I can step through the Sub and see where ToBePopulatedVariables(0) - which is the variable A - has the value "STARTVALUE" and then that value is changes to "TheNewValue".

But when control is passed back to the calling code the value of a reverts back to "STARTVALUE".

I've tried everything I can think of. Any ideas?

---

Both @karl-anderson and Nadeem_MK suggest the same thing.

But

```
Dim a As String()
a(0) = "FirstVariable"
PopulateDataSet("Management", {a})
```

Returns “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”

When assigning the value to a(0)

However

```
Dim a As String() = {"FirstVariable"}
```

Does run.

But I’m still stuck with the new value not being returned to the calling code. I've tried doing this ByVal and ByRef but for Arrays I don't think it matters. –

Comment: Strings are immutable in .Net.  Changing the value of the first element of the array, does not change the string that `a` points to.  Instead it creates a new string and makes the first element of the array point to that string.

Answer (score 1):

Is this vb.Net? If so, I think your array declaration is wrong.
Try this;

```
Dim a(0) As String
a(0) = "STARTVALUE"

PopulateDataSet("Management", a)

Public Sub PopulateDataSet(ByRef SomeRandomOtherVariable As String, ByRef ToBePopulatedVariables() As String)

    ToBePopulatedVariables(0) = "TheNewValue"

End Sub
```

Comment: You should set an initial size for the array. Otherwise a(0) or any other element does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

In your last edit, you are trying to assing a value to an empty array so it should launch an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception, you need to specify the array bounds when declaring:

```
Dim a(0) As String
a(0) = "FirstValue"
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
Dim a As String() = {"FirstValue"}
```

The first code that you posted on your question worked nice (fixing some syntax), and this next modification that I did is working too, if you still experiencing problems with the array bounds/values then possibly the error is in other part of your code. To be ensure that is not a variable problem, declare it out of any method like in this example.

```
Public Class Form1
Private a As String()

Private Sub Test() ' Handles MyBase.Shown
    PopulateDataSet("Hello", a) : MsgBox(a.First)
    PopulateDataSet("World!", a, 5) : MsgBox(a(5))
    PopulateDataSet("I've said Hello World!", a, 10) : MsgBox(a.Last)
End Sub

Public Sub PopulateDataSet(ByVal NewValue As String,
                           ByRef Array As String(),
                           Optional ByVal ItemIndex As Integer = 0)

    If Array Is Nothing Then
        System.Array.Resize(Array, 1)
    ElseIf Not Array.Count > ItemIndex Then
        Do Until Array.Count > ItemIndex
            System.Array.Resize(Array, Array.Count + 1)
        Loop
    End If

    Array(ItemIndex) = NewValue

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Think a moment about what you're actually doing here:

```
Dim a As String = "STARTVALUE"

PopulateDataSet("Management", {a})
```

You create a string called `a` with the value `STARTVALUE`. Then you create a new array (`{a}`) which contains `a`. You call `PopulateDataSet`, which replaces the first element of the array.

Why don't you see a change?

The variable `a` is not changed at all, it's still `STARTVALUE`.
You don't have a reference to the array you created, so you won't be able to observe the change to that array (it could even been garbage collected already).

Also, `PopulateDataSet` does not return anything, it just changes `ToBePopulatedVariables`. There's also no need for `ByRef`.

You should simply pass a variable that holds an array:

```
Dim a As String() = {"STARTVALUE"}
PopulateDataSet("Management", a)
```

so you can access `a` (which is an array, not a string) after the call to `PopulateDataSet`.